# How to show short message on button hover in React native app

Tags: reactjs, button, hover, native

My mobile App has button with icon only. I want to show information when user just hover over the button.
I tried react-native-element tool tip , but it will work only if we click the button. I need real functionality to work on button click. Is there any other way to show short messages.

Comment: "react-bootstrap" package has nice tooltip which works on both hover and click

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.
Please take some time to read the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for Minimal, Reproducible Example for getting better answers from community.